# Navigation Bar with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i wanna make "block color" on my navigationbar with bootstrap. like this :

[image]

i used nav-pills for that. but i got nothing. block color is not showing. This is my code :

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>paketsatu">Service</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; background-color: #fff; border: 0;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>paketsatu">Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `navbar-nav` instead of nav-pills